# What is the recommended way of setting relations/associations (one-to-many/one-to-one/many-to-many) between entities in REST?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an `Organization` entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Organization implements Serializable {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence", sequenceName = "my_id_sequence",     allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "id_sequence")
private Long id;
private String name;

@JoinColumn(name="organization_id", nullable = false)
@OneToMany
private List<Identifier> identifiers;
}
```

And `Identifier` entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Identifier implements Serializable {
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_sequence_identifier", sequenceName = "my_id_sequence_identifier", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "id_sequence_identifier")
private Long id;
private String system;
private String value;
}
```

I need to implement endpoint which will set//remove one-to-many relation between the two `Organization` and `Identifier` entities.

I am thinking about implementing a separate endpoint for this, which will accept IDs of `Organization` & `Identifier` and set remove a relation between them.
Here's the `RelationshipController` code:

```
@Slf4j
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/relationships")
@RestController
public class RelationshipController {

private final StudentService studentService;

public RelationshipController(StudentService studentService) {
    this.studentService = studentService;
}

@PostMapping
public void setRelationship(@Valid @RequestBody RelationshipDTO relationshipDTO) {
    studentService.setRelationship(relationshipDTO);
}
}
```

`RelationshipDTO`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "course_student")
@Entity
@IdClass(Relationship.RelationshipId.class)
public class Relationship implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "organization_id")
private Long organizationId;

@Id
@Column(name = "identifier_id")
private Long identifierId;

@Data
public static class RelationshipId implements Serializable {
    private Long studentId;

    private Long courseId;
}
}
```

But what's the best practices for the tasks like this?